# Windows 8 - Windows are flashing?

Tags: windows-8

I have a weird issue with my PC that is beginning to drive me nuts: Flashing Windows.

I do a lot of multi-tasking on two-monitors and occasionally, one of the windows on my primary, secondary monitors will flash, sometimes even the window I am currently using will flash.

What is the cause of this and how can I stop it?

**System Specs:**

Processor

```
Intel i5 4690K Quad Core OC 4.2GHz
6 MB cache
Be Quiet Shadow Rock Slim Cooler
Memory
8GB 1600MHz DDR3
Configuration: 2 x 4 GB
2 x DIMM
Motherboard
MSI Z97M-G43
Hard Drive
128GB Solid State Drive (SATA 6.0GBs)
2TB 7200rpm SATA III (SATA 6.0GBs)
Optical Drive
24x DVD+R Optical Drive
Software
Operating System: Windows 8.1 64-Bit
Display
X2 Acer 24" V246HLbd LED VGA DVI Monitor - 5ms Response Time
Graphics
Nvidia GTX 970 4GB GDDR5
```

Comment: More information should be provided. Type of video card used, types of monitors, resolution and refresh settings for both. Usually the issue is video card and refresh related.

Comment: Are the windows blinking in a deliberate pattern or is it more of a random flickering? If it is the former then check **Control Panel->Ease of Access Center->Use text or visual alternatives for sounds** and make sure you don't have **Sound Sentry** enabled.

Comment: 2-3 flashes. I assumed it was the OS notifying me there had been a change within the window, as this particularly happens with browsers

Comment: @MichaelWiggins: Have you checked to see if the *"Use text or visual alternatives for sounds"* options are set?

Comment: I haven't no and am currently away from home, I shall check when I get back to my desk

Comment: Is it happening to Windows Explorer windows only? If so, is it specific to any one storage device? I think that your graphics/monitor setup is unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Can't remember the exact solution though, but I believe it had something to do with the USB ports and/or torrent downloading. Whenever I exited the torrent client, that happened. And I was downloading directly to my external hard drive. So that might be it, if you are in the similar situation.